# Getting coordinates in Google Maps. Angular

Tags: javascript

I would like to receive the coordinates of a point when I click on the map.
I have a Google Maps map in an Angular project, I want to receive coordinates to place a marker there.

//////// please help me

[my html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J8rD.png)

[TS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUvQc.png)

Comment: Please post your code inside question, not as images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.